# Nativescript + Socket.io implementation and ListView not showing before any action on app

Tags: angular, socket.io, rxjs, nativescript

I am working on a chat app with NativeScript with Socket.io.

My problem is ListView items do not show before any action on Chat page such as Taping an action item.

I think my lack of understanding RxJs and it's Observables causing this.

I am sharing my chat service, chat component and chat view. Any suggestions about my code would helps.

Nativescript version: 2.3.0
RxJs version: 5.0.0-beta.12

This is my chat.service.ts file. I implement an angular1 $broadcast $on ability with Observables.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable, Observer } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { SocketIO } from 'nativescript-socketio';
import { Config } from '../../shared/config';

import * as localStorage from 'application-settings';

export interface Chat {
    id: string
}

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
    observable: Observable<any>;
    observer: Observer<any>;
    credentials: any;
    constructor(private socket: SocketIO) {
        this.credentials = {
            email: localStorage.getString('email'),
            CREDENTIAL_ID: localStorage.getString('CREDENTIAL_ID'),
            accountId: localStorage.getString('accountId')
        };

        this.socket = new SocketIO(Config.socketUrl, {});

        this.observable = Observable.create((observer:Observer<any>) => {
            this.observer = observer;
            // Connecting socket after observebale created
            this.connect();
        }).share();

        this.socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('Socket Connected...')
            this.introduceAgent();
        });

        this.socket.on('chatsListGenerated', (response) => {
            let parsedData = JSON.parse(response);
            let chatList: Chat[] = parsedData.data.chats;
            this.$broadcast('chatsListGenerated', chatList);
        });

        this.socket.on('introduceCompleted', (response) => {
            let parsedData = JSON.parse(response);
            this.$broadcast('introduceCompleted', parsedData.data);
            this.getChats();
        });

    }

    $broadcast(event, data) {
        this.observer.next({event: event, data: data});
    }

    $on(eventName, callback) {
        this.observable.filter((data) => {
            return data.event === eventName;
        })
        .map((data) => data.data)
        .subscribe(
            callback,
            (error) => console.log(error)
        );
    }

    connect() {
        this.socket.connect();
    }

    introduceAgent() {
        this.socket.emit('introduceAgent', {
            email: this.credentials.email,
            CREDENTIAL_ID: this.credentials.CREDENTIAL_ID
        });
    }

    getChats() {
        this.socket.emit('getChats', { });
    }
}
```

And this is my chat.component.ts. Component listens broadcast from service and getting chat list

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AgentActionBar } from '../../shared/agent-actionbar/agent-actionbar.component';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { SocketIO } from 'nativescript-socketio';
import { ChatService, Chat } from './chats.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'chats',
  templateUrl: './pages/chats/chats.component.html',
  entryComponents: [ AgentActionBar ],
  providers: [ ChatService, SocketIO ]
})
export class ChatsComponent implements OnInit{
  chatList: Chat[];
  chatListGenerated: Boolean;
  constructor(private chatService: ChatService) {
    this.chatListGenerated = false;
  }

  ngOnInit () {
    this.chatService.$on('chatsListGenerated', (response) => {
      console.log('chat list generated', JSON.stringify(response));
      this.chatList = response;
      this.chatListGenerated = true;
    });
  }
}
```

AgentActionbar is a custom actionbar.

This is my chat view

```
<AgentActionBar></AgentActionBar>

<StackLayout *ngIf="chatListGenerated">
    <ListView [items]="chatList">
        <template let-item="item">
            <Label [text]="item.id"></Label>
        </template>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

I tried **async** pipe,

Returning a Observable to componenet and using **async** pipe. This time I get an error which is **Cannot read property 'Symbol' of undefined**
Can not even render list.

```
this.socket.on('chatsListGenerated', (response) => {
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(response);
    let chatList: Chat[] = parsedData.data.chats;
    let obChatList$ = Observable.from(chatList);
    this.$broadcast('chatsListGenerated', obChatList$);
});
```

I think I am doing something very wrong or I am facing a bug. All help counts. Excuse my English and thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you strip this to only the most necessary parts?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am having the same issue too